# Remove special characters like lt; but not anchor tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

How can I remove special characters like ;lt ;gt but not Anchor tag 
e.g

```
&amp;lt;a href=&amp;quot;http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0005069/&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Spike Jonze&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt; This cause by <a class="primary-black" href="http://example.com/community/RobHallums">RobHallums</a>
```

should be

```
Spike Jonze This cause by <a class="primary-black" href="http://example.com/community/RobHallums">RobHallums</a>
```

Comment: Show us what you tried please.

Comment: i want to remove lt; gt; like tags but not removed <a> from string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick one for you:

```
<?php

// SET OUR DEFAULT STRING
$string = '&amp;lt;a href=&amp;quot;http://w...content-available-to-author-only...b.com/name/nm0005069/&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Spike Jonze&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt; This cause by <a class="primary-black" href="http://e...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/community/RobHallums">RobHallums</a>';

// USE PREG_REPLACE TO STRIP OUT THE STUFF WE DON'T WANT
$string = preg_replace('~&amp;lt;.*?&amp;gt;~', '', $string);

// PRINT OUT OUR NEW STRING
print $string;
```

All I'm doing here is looking for `&amp;lt;`, followed by any character `.`, any number of times `*`, until it matches the next part of the string `?`, which is `&amp;gt;`.

Any time it finds that, it replaces it with nothing.  So you're left with the text you want.

Here is a working demo:

http://ideone.com/uSnY0b

Answer (score 0):

use html_entity_decode:

```
<?php $url = html_entity_decode('&amp;lt;a href=&amp;quot;http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0005069/&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Spike Jonze&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;'); 
echo $url;
?>
```

the output will be:

```
<a href="http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0005069/">Spike Jonze</a>
```

EDIT:

```
<?php 
  preg_match_all('/<a .*?>(.*?)<\/a>/',$url,$matches);
  //For Text Name
  echo $matches[1][0]; //output : Spike Jonze
?>
```

Comment: But i want to remove all text which is in between lt;a but not removed anker tag output should be "Spike Jonze"

Comment: strip_tags remove all tags from string but not want to remove word that have already prensent in <a format whole output would be 'Spike Jonze This cause by <a class="primary-black" href="http://example.com/community/RobHallums">RobHallums</a>'